# Jtable options array for drop down list or select list

Tags: list, object, html-select, jquery-jtable

I've been trying to create an object to use in a jtable as the options (for a select list).
I don't seem to have the format correct.  The jtable.org website says it will take an array:

From the jtable.org website:

http://jtable.org/ApiReference#fopt-options

```
PhoneType: {
title: 'Phone type',
options: [{ Value: '1', DisplayText: 'Home phone' }, { Value: '2', DisplayText: 'Office phone' }, { Value: '2', DisplayText: 'Cell phone' }]
```

}

However, when I create an object like that:

```
            var optionsObject = [];
            optionsObject.push({Value: i, DisplayText: 'Hello' + i});
```

and then use it as a variable for the options in my jtable:

```
                            key: true,
                        options: optionsObject,
```

I don't get the items in the select list drop down.  I do get something in the select list, but that looks like '[object Object]' instead of the actual items.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

If I send an object that looks like this:

```
object.push('hello' + i);
```

I will get an item in the select list that looks like this 'hello0', as expected, but then the display text is also used as the value.  I need to have an object with separate display texts and values.

Has anybody had any success with doing this?

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, and debugger stops in the jtable scripting files, I learned that in order to use an object for the 'options' property of a field in jtable, the object must be in the following format

```
var optionsObject = new Object();
optionsObject[Value] = DisplayText;
```